# At what value is f(x) continuous for all x>0?

Tags: calculus, continuity

For 
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
 \frac{x^3-1}{x-1} &\text{for $x \ne 1$},\\[3ex]
 k&\text{for $x=1$}.
\end{cases}
$$

What is the value of $k$ for which $f(x)$ is continuous?

I have attempted to factor the above to find where $f(x)$ is $= 0$.

Is it proper to say $x^2+x+1$ is simplification of $f(x)$?  If so then the derivative of $f(x)$ would be $2x+1$.  If I set the derivative equal to zero would that provide my answer? In this case ans. $-1/2$

Comment: You need $\lim \limits_{x\to 1^+}f(x)=\lim \limits_{x\to 1^-}f(x)=f(1)$ for $f$ to be continuous at $x=1$.

Comment: You can surely say that $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ for $x\ne 1$. Then… Note that derivatives are not involved in any way with this. The answer is not $-1/2$.

Answer (score 5):

Clearly $f(x)$ is continuous at $x \neq 1$ since at (and in the neighborhood of) those points it equals a rational function. Now calculate $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x)$.

$$
\lim_{x\to 1} \frac{x^3 -1}{x-1} = \lim_{x\to 1} \frac{(x^2 + x +1) (x -1)}{x-1}
 = \lim_{x\to 1}  (x^2 + x +1) =3,
$$
so $\lim_{x \to 1} f(x) =3$. To make $f(x)$ continuous at $x=1$, we need $f(1)=\lim_{x \to 1}f(x)$. This will be accomplished if and only if $k=3$.

The derivative is not needed to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it proper to say $x^2+x+1$ is simplification of $f(x)$?

Sort of. Away from $x=1$, the function $f(x)$ is indeed identical to $x^2 + x + 1$. However, $f(x)$ may or may not be identical to $x^2 + x + 1$ at the point $x=1$, depending on the value of $k$.

I'm not sure what you were trying to do to solve the problem: however, a simple argument from the above observation tells us what we need to know: if $f$ is continuous, then we have to have $f(x) = x^2 + x + 1$ everywhere.